# Series of 1s and 0s, probability of hitting a specific string before another string

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-probability

The question:

> A person playing a game randomly chooses a number, $1$ or $0$. He keeps choosing them, creating a number made of $1$s and $0$s.

> For example, choosing $1$, then five $0$s and then two $1$s gives the number $10000011$

> If at any point the last four digits of the number are $0010$, he wins. If the last four digits are $1001$, he loses.

> Find the probability that he wins.

At first I thought to build a Markov chain with the 16 states from $0000$ to $1111$, but then finding out the probabilities would require a lot of matrix multiplication. Also the number can go on indefinitely with series of a single digit, which makes things difficult. (Vectors of hitting probability also have the same problem)

So I thought to use conditional probability. Let the probability that he wins, given the first choice is a $1$, be $x$, and for $0$, $y$.

Here something cool happens. Long series of $1$s and $0$s, specifically of length more than $3$, can be treated as having length $3$ anyway. For example, say the choices are $1$, and then the choice keeps being zeroes. Since a $1$ has to be chosen again eventually (because otherwise the game never ends) this is the same as $1000$.

One could also say that choosing a long string of $0$s is equivalent to starting a game with a choice of $001$.

So I can calculate the probability of winning after $1000..._{\{\text{some amount of 0s}\}}...0$. Since a 1 must eventually come, we are left with the last three digits $001$. Here the probability of choosing $0$ and winning is $\frac12$. The probability of choosing $1$ is $\frac12$, and this is equivalent to starting a game with a first choice as $1$, in which the probability of winning is already defined as $x$. Thus giving the probability of winning after $1000...0$ to be $\frac12+\frac x2$.

I cannot see how to go further.

Please help.

Comment: You don't need all possible states, just the relevant ones.  $0$, $00$, $001$, $1$, $10$, $100$ (and the two END states.

Comment: Related: [Penney's Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penney%27s_game)

Comment: @lulu But what do I do then? Even then I should have to do quite a few matrix multiplications right? (I only learned about Markov chains for this question, so I don't really know much about them.)

Comment: It's just a bunch of simultaneous linear equations.  Not that bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labelling the start as $s$, and other sequences (*states*) as below:

$0=a,\quad 00=b,\quad 001=c,\quad 1=d,\quad 10=e,\quad 100=f$

Tracing the route to $0010$ victory, we get the equations

$s=.5(a+d), \;\; a=.5(b+d),\;\; d=.5(e+d),\;\;b=.5(c +b),\;\; e= .5(f+d)$

$c=.5(d+1)\;\;$[The $+1$ to ensure victory for $0010$]

$f=.5(b+0)\;\;$[The $+0$ to ensure defeat for opponent]

[Solving the equations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=s%3D.5%28a%2Bd%29+%2C+a%3D.5%28b%2Bd%29%2C+d%3D.5%28e%2Bd%29%2C+b%3D.5%28c+%2Bb%29%2C+e%3D+.5%28f%2Bd%29%2C+c%3D.5%28d%2B1%29+%2C+f%3D.5%28b%2B0%29) gives $P(0010)$ wins $= \dfrac{5}{12}$

Comment: Why choose these specific states instead of others? 101 for example. Alternatively, starting from 0 and 1, how do I build the necessary states and find out which are unnecessary?

Comment: $101$ for this game just becomes the starting $1$ because that is the only thing on which you can build. Actually, it is not that I have chosen the blocks, rather they get chosen automatically. Each toss has two outcomes, and we draw arrows to where each leads. The $6$ blocks I wrote were not **initially** chosen, they got chosen by drawing the network.